# Reactive forms without initial view model in Vue and Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

We are using forms for inserting new record or updating existing records (Update record scenerio includes view record scenerio)

Update record scenerio is easy one .

https://codepen.io/glikoz/pen/YjbeMY

But if we want to create "insert form" we don't have record, maybe we can create empty one. This resolves problem but we have to fill each property with null (Do you know any C# library for it :))

```
data:
{
errors:[],
name:null,
age:null,
movie:null,
city:{
  id:null,
  name:null
     }
}
```

So for creating "insert form" normally we don't have a record (instance). 
But if don't give record to viewModel, we are getting "cannot read property 'name' of undefined (city property is undefined)

This is natural viewmodel for insert form:

```
data: {
errors:[]
 }
```

For seeing problem:

https://codepen.io/glikoz/pen/NBVOOe

I expect that v-model binding must handle this problem, is there any library, directive, approach to solve this problem?

**Update (What's wrong with just creating an "instance")**

I'm preparing "Insert forms" dynamically (template and data) and sending them to client side, than I'm rendering them (template and data)  using this great work-> https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template on client side.

So creating "empty" instance with each nested property is seems a little wrong.
I want to say that to component:
***"You are component and I bind you with my model, If you could not find your data in my model, stop throwing exception show your default(empty) version"***

I know what can I do to solve the problem in javascript -> https://medium.com/javascript-inside/safely-accessing-deeply-nested-values-in-javascript-99bf72a0855a
But I don't know Vue enough :(

Comment: What's wrong with just creating an "instance"?

Comment: @Traxo I've added response to end of the question

Comment: Bind can not do its job if the specified variable does not exist in your component data - but you can use a workaround http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/274500/